# How can I use scan/scroll with pagination and sort in ElasticSearch?

Tags: python-2.7, sorting, elasticsearch, scroll, pagination

I have a ES DB storing history records from a process I run every day. Because I want to show only 20 records per page in the history (order by date), I was using pagination (size + from_) combined scroll, which worked just fine. But when I wanted to used sort in the query it didn't work. So I found that scroll with sort don't work. Looking for another alternative I tried the ES helper scan which works fine for scrolling and sorting the results, but with this solution pagination doesn't seem to work, which I don't understand why since the API says that scan sends all the parameters to the underlying search function. So my question is if there is any method to combine the three options.

Thanks,

Ruben

Answer (score 5):

When using the `elasticsearch.helpers.scan` function, you need to pass `preserve_order=True` to enable sorting.

(Tested using `elasticsearch==7.5.1`)

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can combine scroll with sort, but, when you can sort string, you will need change the mapping for it works fine, [Documentation Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-fields.html)

> In order to sort on a string field, that field should contain one term
>   only: the whole not_analyzed string. But of course we still need the
>   field to be analyzed in order to be able to query it as full text.
>
> The naive approach to indexing the same string in two ways would be to
>   include two separate fields in the document: one that is analyzed for
>   searching, and one that is not_analyzed for sorting.

```
"tweet": { 
    "type":     "string",
    "analyzer": "english",
    "fields": {
        "raw": { 
            "type":  "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
}
```

> - The main **tweet** field is just the same as before: an **analyzed**    full-text field.
> - The new **tweet.raw** subfield is **not_analyzed**.
>
> Now, or at least as soon as we have reindexed our data, we can use the
>   **`tweet` field for search** and the **`tweet.raw` field for sorting**:

```
GET /_search
    {
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "tweet": "elasticsearch"
            }
        },
        "sort": "tweet.raw"
    }
```

Comment: No I can't. If I use the scroll command the results I get are not sorted. Also I am not sorting on a string field.

Comment: You tried change the field mapping to not_analyzed? What field type you will sort?

Comment: Yes I tried changing it to not_analyzed but still doesn't work. I am filtering by date

Comment: When you see the mappping? It is `{"type":"date","format":"dateOptionalTime"}`?

Comment: Yes it is. But I don't think the problem is with the format of the field I am sorting with but the combination of sort, scroll and pagination. I can sort if I don't use scroll and I can use pagination with search but not when ordering...

Comment: Please, Edit the question and give me an example of you data, mapping and search query... because I have the same scenario and work perfect.